# vs 2012 when publishing removes references to project dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dll, publish

This just started happening all the sudden, when I run my asp.net project locally it runs fine and compiles fine.  But when I want to publish it, it seems that if looses or eliminates a reference to a dll file.  [image: before/after screenshot]

as you can see in the image before publishing it recognizes the dll and as soon as I hit "publish" and it starts building it "removes" or "looses" the dll reference.  I've tried removing the dll and adding it back in, restarting computer, clearing temp files and nothing doing. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have the `Copy Local` property of the reference set to `True`?

Comment: wheres that at? and why would all the sudden do this? Ive been publishing for a year now this project and never had any problems

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the `Copy Local` property of the reference:

[image: Copy Local]

This happens to me randomly sometimes in VS2012. I haven't found a reason why.. but setting it back to True fixes the problem.

Comment: tried it and it still won't work.  Trying to publish from a diff computer not sure if that'll work. :(